# Node red after successful installation of google map but still it is not showing in GUI (ie drag and drop button for google map)

Tags: node.js, google-maps

Node red successfully installed google map through npm command but still we are not able to see on GUI (ie drag and drop button of google map). Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the package.json file [You will able to discover package.json in GitHub once you saved project in GitHub]
2. In package.json file, there is "dependencies" parameter
3. In "dependencies" ,you just need to add google node with version:

Example:

```
{
    "name"         : "iot-bluemix",
    "version"      : "0.5.03",
    "dependencies": {
        "when": "~3.x",
        "mongodb": "~1.4.x",
        "nano": "~5.11.0",
        "cfenv":"~1.0.0",
        "feedparser":"~0.19.2",
        "redis":"~0.10.1",
        "node-red": "0.x",
        "node-red-bluemix-nodes":"1.x",
        "node-red-node-watson":"0.x",
        "node-red-node-openwhisk":"0.x",
        "node-red-node-cf-cloudant":"0.x",
        "node-red-contrib-scx-ibmiotapp":"0.x",
        "node-red-contrib-ibm-wiotp-device-ops":"0.x",
        "node-red-contrib-iot-virtual-device":"0.x",
        "node-red-contrib-ibmpush":"0.x",
        "node-red-contrib-bluemix-hdfs":"0.x"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node --max-old-space-size=384 node_modules/node-red/red.js --settings ./bluemix-settings.js -v"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "4.x"
    }
}
```